# Best way to use the current URL as a parameter to external API in javascript

Tags: javascript, fetch, privacy, http-referer, referrer-policy

I would like to know what is the best way fetch a resource from our client's site to our servers with the Fetch API (GET). In order to do so we need to send the current URL since the resource depends on that.

We've come up with two choices so far:

- Sending the current URL encoded with `encodeURIComponent` as part of the query string. Could be also base64 if it is safer. In this case, which is the best function that is PHP compatible for decoding?
- Using the `referer` header of the HTTP Request. We found out that this works without additional effort but the default value for this is not consistent among browsers due to privacy concerns [1]. We could try to force the referrer Policy to `no-referrer-when-downgrade` for this particular request but in doing so we wouldn't want to hurt the user's privacy.

Thanks

[1] https://web.dev/referrer-best-practices/

Comment: Why not send it in the POST body?

Comment: Those two options are your best options since you're calling a `GET` API. StackOverflow is not a great place to determine which is "best"; it's all a matter of weighing tradeoffs. Personally I'd stick with the `referer` header.

Comment: GET is for client side retrieval of information. It is NOT for information transfer. You should use POST or PUT: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PUT

Comment: Ok, so you can only use GET...? Why? And: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php

Comment: @Jacob I'm requesting data from the client to our servers. I'm not creating or updating any resource. That is the choice for a GET verb. That is why it is used in the first place: retrieval of information. Why would it be more appropiate the other way you mention?

Comment: @DraQ I didn't suggest you shouldn't not use `GET`; @ChrisG and @ControlAltDel did.

Comment: If you are afraid that a GET request might not be 100% safe, just use POST instead. Yes, you are requesting something. But you also want a safe way to transmit a URL, and POST is just that; and sending back a resource will work just fine either way.

Comment: A referer header might not be very useful as it's subject to filtering (or even removal) by CSP config.